# fancybox seems to not working with ajax content

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I've got the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("a#cakeImages").live("click",function() fancybox({
        'titleShow'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
    })) 
});
```

and I've got the correct images :

```
<a id="cakeImages" href="cakes/2/1.jpg" > 
<img alt="cakeImages" class="align-left no-border" src="cakes/2/1.jpg"  /></a>
```

But it's not working at all. I use .live, because my actual images change due to the ajax script on the page.

But when I only change it to :

```
$(document).ready(function() {$("a#cakeImages").fancybox({
            'titleShow'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
     }) 
});
```

Works only the firs time. 
Has anyone has a clue, what's going on ? :D

Comment: function() fancybox( <--- what is this?

Answer (score 3):

With tips from Saikat and Nick, I've managed to come up with code that works with a gallery of images. Instead of just the one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[rel=gallery]").live('click', function(){
        $("a[rel=gallery]").filter(':not(.fb)').fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',           
        'titlePosition' : 'over'
        }).addClass('fb');
        $(this).triggerHandler('click');
        return false;
    });
});
```

What it does. When ajax finish loading the images on the page. On first click on any link with the "rel=gallery" group, it will load the fancybox event on those that does not have a "fb" class. If it does, it won't trigger it the second time but goes straight to the triggerHandler.

Hope this helps all trying to get fancybox work with a gallery of images.
I haven't tested this on single image ajax loads, but I assume it'll work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a old thread but I found it when I was looking for the answer to it so here it goes:
if you are using the default

`<a href="somewere.com" class="something"><img src="myimage.jpg" /></a>`

using ajax the first answer started to open then went to the url anyway so I changed the fancybox call to the following :

```
`$(".fancybox").live("click", function(event) {`
     `event.preventDefault();`
         `$(this).filter(':not(.fb)').fancybox()`
         `.addClass('fb');`
         `$(this).triggerHandler('click');`

    `});`
```

the first answer got me thinking about what was going on in the Fancybox call, the `event.preventDefault();` it the missing part of the first answer in my case.

Hope this help someone.
BTW thanks Petyp for pushing the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only *binding* the fancybox on the first click, not opening it you'll need to actually trigger it's handler, via [`.triggerHandler()`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) to get it to open after that binding, like this:

```
$(function(){ 
  $("a#cakeImages").live("click", function() {
     $(this).filter(':not(.fb)').fancybox({
       'titleShow'      : false,
       'transitionIn'   : 'elastic',
       'transitionOut'  : 'elastic'
     }).addClass('fb');
     $(this).triggerHandler('click');
  });
});
```

What this does is listen for clicks on `<a id="cakeImages">` elements (there should only be one at a time, use a class instead of an ID if this isn't the case) and if we haven't already run the `.fancybox()` (it doesn't have the `fb` class, check via [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)) then do so and assign the class (via [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)), the next click it won't run this, only trigger the click handler, which will open the fancybox.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { $(function(){ 
  $("a#cakeImages").live("click", function() {
     $(this).filter(':not(.fb)').fancybox({
       'titleShow'      : false,
       'transitionIn'   : 'elastic',
       'transitionOut'  : 'elastic'
     }).addClass('fb');
     $(this).triggerHandler('click');
  });
}); });
</script>`

.......
`<a id="cakeImages" href="cakes/1/1.jpg" >     <img alt="cakeImages" class="align-left no-border" src="cakes/1/1.jpg"   /></a>`
....................
That's what I got now, however I cant seem to run it properly. Any ideas :?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){                      
    $("a.previewfancy").live("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).filter(':not(.fb)').fancybox()
         .addClass('fb');
         $(this).triggerHandler('click');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers from Roy and Nick, I have the complete solution working wonderfully inside an Ajax function.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[rel=gallery]").live('click', function(){
        $("a[rel=gallery]").filter(':not(.fb)').fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',           
        'titlePosition' : 'over'
        }).addClass('fb');
        $(this).triggerHandler('click');
        return false;
    });
});
        $(function(){ 
  $("a.fancybox").live("click", function() {
     $(this).filter(':not(.fb)').fancybox({
       'titleShow'      : false,
       'transitionIn'   : 'elastic',
       'transitionOut'  : 'elastic'
     }).addClass('fb');
     $(this).triggerHandler('click');
  });
});
```